# Why I am getting value error in my location finding function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-2.0

I need your help to figure out my mistake in my code.

I am trying to auto fill the latitude/longitude fields once user entered the address. So in location field map will be shown and both fields will be auto filled.

models.py:

```
from location_field.models.plain import PlainLocationField
class Store(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, related_name='building', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(default='Singapore')
    latitude = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(-90.0), MaxValueValidator(90.0)])
    longitude = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(-180.0), MaxValueValidator(180.0)])
    location = PlainLocationField(based_fields=['address'], zoom=7, null=True)

    @property
    def latitude(self):
        if not self.location:
            return
        try:
            print('Store Location1: ' + str(self.location))
            latitude, _ = self.location.split(',')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception1: ' + str(e))
        print("latitude:", latitude)
        return latitude

    @property
    def longitude(self):
        if not self.location:
            return
        try:
            print('Store Location2: ' + str(self.location))
            _, longitude = self.location.split(',')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception2: ' + str(e))
        print("longitude:", longitude)
        return longitude
```

When start my server I saw following two print statements-

```
Store Location1: 8 SHENTON WAY #43-01 AXA TOWER Singapore
Exception1: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The print statement in longitude functions are never printed.And when I go to my store it shows following error in browser-

```
File "E:\mysite\models.py", line 216, in latitude
latitude, _ = self.location.split(',')
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Can anyone please help me to find out the exact issue?

Comment: In the string you print, there is no comma. So splitting the string on comma will result in a list of a single element, which can't be unpacked into two variables.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, it was my mistake. So can you tell me how can I change my function code so that it will work?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but your `latitude` and `longitude` properties shadow the eponym fields.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree, I will remove both properties from the code as well as from db also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unpack an iterable of size one into two variables. Here's the *minimal* example for your problem.

```
mystr = 'Store Location1: 8 SHENTON WAY #43-01 AXA TOWER Singapore'

latitude, _ = mystr.split(',')

# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Note there is no comma in your input string. Therefore, you need to refactor your logic or ensure your data upstream is appropriate.

For example, if you want `location` to represent the first split only:

```
latitude = mystr.split(', ', 1)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks jpp, I got it, it was my mistake. So can you tell me how can I change my function code so that it will work?

Comment: I mean what to change in my latitude and longitude functions.Do I need to remove both?

Comment: @AnalyticsPy, I'm afraid this is far beyond the scope of resolving your error. To fix your workflow, I would need to work with a [mcve]. Feel free to wait a while longer if this isn't possible.

Comment: it's my bad. The changes you have mentioned for latitude is working now and for longitude what should I do?

Comment: @AnalyticsPy, I suspect the issue is similar. To identify the problem, `print` the string beforehand, if it can't be split by `,`, then find out what you need and change your logic.

Comment: Thanks @jpp. When I see the printed value of latitude it is exactly same as location value, but as per the PlainLocationField pckage it should give the latitude value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173468/discussion-between-jpp-and-analyticspy).

Comment: @AnalyticsPy, Sorry, I can't help further without understanding your application. Feel free to post a new question with your specific problem after having resolved this `ValueError` issue. Maybe someone from `django` / geophysics community might be able to help.